# Custom draw selection rectangle

Tags: c#, selection, custom-draw

I am working on a custom control based on a ListView control. The goal of the control is to show the events name in the first column and the event duration on a timeline on the second column. I've implemented the custom drawing for the timeline section and it all works.

Now I would like to implement a "zooming" feature. Where the user would be able to click somewhere on the second column drag the mouse and upon release the timeline would be zoomed in with starting and end times matching the mousedown/mouseup events.

Currently when I click/drag the mouse, a normal selection box appears. I would like to overide that such that I get don't get a box but more of a vertical area (so the selection is only based on the timeline axis).

I really don't know where to look and how to overide the drawing the selection box. Any pointers/sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't need multi selection option setting `MultiSelect` property to `false` disables rubber band selection.

Comment: Ok, that's a start :). Now how do I draw my own?

Comment: [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314945) is code for rubber band selection drawing. I think you could adjust that code to fit your needs.